# style: n×n-matrix

Tags: math-mode

```
 Writing about $n\times n$-matrices like this gives bad spacing.
```

[image: same sentence]

What's the correct way?

Comment: Don't use  the hyphen – and no capital M.  A simple word space is enough.

Comment: Sorry for the capital M mistake. I updated the question.

Comment: you are right. The English literature I scanned it was written without a hyphen. BUT: Every German book I checked used the hyphen. Unfortunately with bad spacing... [take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joRMx.png)

Comment: You also can use a capital M if you decide the write in pre-nineteenth century English… :o)

Comment: Have you tried `$n{\times}n$-matrices`? (The curly braces change the math-status of `\times` from math-rel to math-ord.)

Comment: I'd find bad the spacing with `$n{\times}n$`. Why should it be different from when you write `$m+n$`?

Comment: @egreg - I agree that `\times` should *not* be given math-ord status, i.e., it should keep status math-rel, if there's a word space between `$n\times n$` and `matrices`. In contrast, if the word space is replaced with a hyphen, the `n\times` component appears (to me at least.) to be visually almost unconnected to the `n-matrices` component. I guess it's the hyphen case that prompted the OP to post this query.  @Bernard's solution -- writing `about $n{\times}n\mkern1.5mu$-matrices`, solves the issue of too little space between `n` and `-`. (My own preference is for dropping the hyphen...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two main options:

- Don't use a hyphen. (This was already mentioned by @Bernard in an earlier comment.)
- Write $n{\times}n$. This converts the math-status of `\times` from relational-operator atom to ordinary atom, resulting in no extra whitespace around $\times$.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Writing about $n\times n$ matrices like this gives ok spacing.

Writing about $n\times n$-matrices like this gives bad spacing.

Writing about $n{\times}n$-matrices like this gives ok spacing.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about one of these?

```
\documentclass{article}%

\begin{document}

$m{\times}n\mkern1.5mu$-Matrix

$(m{,}n)$-Matrix

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is good but a bit strange.

Comment: What's strange?